# Stuck in rvm, capistrano, :system, :user revolving door

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

What is the best practice for installing ruby, gemset for on a server. I currently have one app and an account with the same name. I will be depoloying other apps in the future on the same VPS.

I have installed rvm system wide on Debian6 using sudo.

Is it better to install app specific gem set at the system ruby location or in ~/.rvm?
What code should I put in deploy.rb to effect one or the other?

I am trying various combinations of commands in deploy.rb but end up with errors, the latest is

```
Gemset 'rails-322' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create rails-322' first, or append '--create'.
```

I am not sure where the rails-322 gemset comes from because I am running rails 3.2.6. Is it a default because I did not specify it anywhere.

I just now created `rvm --rvmrc ---create 1.9.3@myapp` in the project directory changed to `set :use_sudo,        true` will see how it goes.

I am finding there are too many books, references which do things a bit differently from each other. I am following
Rails3 in Action - Katz
Deploying Rails - Burns books.

The problem I am having is gleaning the correct code for my app as I am not running vagrant but deploying to a VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're installing this server primarily for installing rails applications or other things that use bundler -- http://gembundler.com/ -- your best bet is just to use bundler for your rails applications and not worry about gem management outside of that.  This will install local bundles with each app.

This is how to add bundler to your capistrano deploy:  http://gembundler.com/deploying.html

This is how to use capistrano and rvm together in a way that has worked for me in the past, but generally this will be more of an issue once you have multiple apps:  https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you. THat worked for me except now I am stuck on another issue with twitter-bootstrap-rails css issue. I will just ask another question.